# Jquery date validation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Date1:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Validate" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addClassRules({
            Date: {
                date: true
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above script is not validating the date..am I missing on something..please help me out..
Thanks.

Comment: A few things: Can you post the HTML generated by ASP.NET? Are you ever actually calling `validate` on a form? Do you have a form on your page at all?

Comment: yes I do have a form and I am calling validate on it..but its still not working

Comment: Is your validator successfully validating anything else on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?:

> Date: {
>       required: true }

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
    $.validator.addClassRules( "Date",
    {
        Date: true
    });
```